# Should a payment success or error page expire?

Tags: patterns-and-practices, payment, notifications

When payment is made, it either succeeds or fails for whatever reason. In this case, though not important, the payment is made on a third party payment website, like Paypal, and a callback url is supplied for success or failure.

My question is should that success or error page expire, that is start returning a 404 after a set time or even immediately after it has been accessed once. There might be no security implications for allowing a notifications page live on forever, so this is more of a best practice question. But if there're security implications, I'll be glad to hear them.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You generally use the same call back for all payments and the 3rd parties API will expect it to always be there and conform to the spec.

Also, returning a 404 generally wont reverse the payment or anything.

If you miss a callback for some reason there is usually a backup polling method you can use to check the status of a payment.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. However, the 404 thing is not really for the payment processor rather for users refreshing the same payment success page maybe days later. The callback url is usually static like https://example.com/payment-callback. But I now see my question only applies where the payment processor allows some sort of dynamic callback like https://example.com/payment-callback?payment-id=foo.
Thanks for the answer, I guess no expiry is the way to go